Assigning Y-Axis with 24 hours range
I am struggling to assign the y-axis with the hour format. I have a data of Islamic prayer time for one whole year and what I am intending to do is to plot 5 prayer times in a graph starting from Jan 24 until Dec 24.
As I plot the graph, the y-axis doesn't show the range of the hours for a day which is from 00:01 until 23:59. It's just showing the range for one particular praying time. In this example, the y-axis just showing Fajr's range time. Here are the codes for your reference. Thanks in advance.

col1 <- "lightblue"
col2 <- "lightgreen"
col3 <- "orange"
col4 <- "pink"
col5 <- "turquoise"

plot(data$Date, data$Fajr, xlab="Date", ylab="Time", cex=0.5, col=col1)

points(data$Date, data$Fajr, pch=19, cex=0.5, col=col1)
points(data$Date, data$Dhuhr, pch=19, cex=0.5, col=col2)
points(data$Date, data$Asr, pch=19, cex=0.5, col=col3)
points(data$Date, data$Maghrib, pch=19, cex=0.5, col=col4)
points(data$Date, data$Isha, pch=19, cex=0.5, col=col5)

legend("bottomright", legend=c("Fajr", "Dhuhr", "Asr", "Maghrib", "Isha"), 
       col=c(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5), pch=19, cex=0.5)

I've tried to use ylim:
ylim_range <- as.POSIXct(c("00:00", "23:59"), format="%H:%M", tz="GMT")

and add this code inside the plot code:
plot(data$Date, data$Fajr, xlab="Date", ylab="Time", cex=0.5, col=col1, 
     ylim=ylim_range)

and it's still doesn't show the y-axis' range that I preferred.
Data:
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1704067200, 1704153600, 1704240000, 
1704326400, 1704412800, 1704499200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Fajr = structure(c(-2209054200, -2209054200, -2209054200, 
-2209054200, -2209054200, -2209054200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Shuruq = structure(c(-2209046040, -2209046040, -2209046100, 
-2209046100, -2209046100, -2209046100), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Dhuha = structure(c(-2209043160, -2209043160, -2209043160, 
-2209043220, -2209043220, -2209043280), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Dhuhr = structure(c(-2209031580, -2209031520, -2209031520, 
-2209031460, -2209031460, -2209031460), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Asr = structure(c(-2209025640, -2209025580, -2209025520, 
-2209025460, -2209025400, -2209025340), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Maghrib = structure(c(-2209017480, -2209017360, -2209017300, 
-2209017240, -2209017180, -2209017120), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Isha = structure(c(-2209009200, -2209009140, -2209009080, 
-2209009020, -2209008960, -2209008900), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `Qibla Hour` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Fajr_numeric = c(5.83333333333333, 
5.83333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 
5.83333333333333), Dhuhr_numeric = c(12.1166666666667, 12.1333333333333, 
12.1333333333333, 12.15, 12.15, 12.15), Asr_numeric = c(13.7666666666667, 
13.7833333333333, 13.8, 13.8166666666667, 13.8333333333333, 13.85
), Maghrib_numeric = c(16.0333333333333, 16.0666666666667, 16.0833333333333, 
16.1, 16.1166666666667, 16.1333333333333), Isha_numeric = c(18.3333333333333, 
18.35, 18.3666666666667, 18.3833333333333, 18.4, 18.4166666666667
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))


Welcome to SO.  It would be helpful to see (some of) your raw data.  Please update your question with the output from dput(data) or, if that's too big, dput(head(data)).

Apologies for the oversight. I've attached the data but I'm not really sure whether it's correct or not. Let me know if it's need some adjustment.

Here is a solution based on the tidyverse.  As you didn't supply any data, I've made the (obviously incorrect) assumption that prayer times do not vary over the year.  (Though the times are accurate for my location today...)  The tidyverse works best with tidy data, so I've used pivot_longer to convert your current (wide) format to long.  The default values I've used create a data frame with columns calendarDate, name (containing the prayer time) and value giving the name of the daily prayer.
Further customisation to give you exactly what you need should be straightforward.
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)
library(lubridate)


d %>% 
  pivot_longer(-calendarDate) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = calendarDate, y = value, colour = name))

giving

Test data
d <- tibble(
  Fajr = parse_hms("02:59:00"),
  Sunrise = parse_hms("04:50:00"),
  Dhuhr = parse_hms("13:03:00"),
  Asr = parse_hms("17:17:00"),
  Maghrib = parse_hms("21:07:00"),
  Isha = parse_hms("22:21:00"),
  calendarDate = seq(as_date("2024-01-01"), as_date("2024-12-31"), "+1 day")
)

Edit
Using the data recently provided by OP,
d %>% 
  select(Date, Fajr, Dhuhr, Asr, Maghrib, Isha) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Date) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = value, colour = name))

gives

The lines are (almost) straingt because the data span only six days rather than a full year.

Thank you for your explanations. I will try as you suggested. Cheers

You had the right intuition. To get the ylim correctly you want the range of the prayer times. Assuming they are in POSIXt format, we could subtract the respective date in POSIXt. Initialize base plot using type='n' and easily Map over the columns with points.
> pr <- names(df)[2:4]
> clrs <- c("lightblue", "lightgreen", "orange")
> plot(data$Date, as.POSIXct(data$Date) - data$Fajr, xlab="Date", ylab="Time", type='n', 
+      ylim=sapply(data[pr], \(x) range(x - as.POSIXct(data$Date))) |> range())
> Map(\(x, y) with(data, points(Date, x - as.POSIXct(data$Date), pch=19, cex=.5, col=y)),
+     data[pr], clrs) |> invisible()
> legend("bottomleft", legend=names(data[pr]), 
+        col=clrs, pch=19, cex=.8, ncol=3, title='Prayers')


In addition, matplot can be quite effective, here a basic example that you may polish with axis and mtext.
> sapply(data[-1] - as.integer(as.POSIXct(data[[1]])), as.integer) |> 
+   matplot(pch=19, cex=.5)



Data:
> dput(data)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19723, 19724, 19725, 19726, 
19727, 19728, 19729, 19730, 19731, 19732, 19733, 19734, 19735, 
19736, 19737, 19738, 19739, 19740, 19741, 19742, 19743, 19744, 
19745, 19746, 19747, 19748, 19749, 19750, 19751, 19752, 19753, 
19754, 19755, 19756, 19757, 19758, 19759, 19760, 19761, 19762, 
19763, 19764, 19765, 19766, 19767, 19768, 19769, 19770, 19771, 
19772, 19773, 19774, 19775, 19776, 19777, 19778, 19779, 19780, 
19781, 19782, 19783, 19784, 19785, 19786, 19787, 19788, 19789, 
19790, 19791, 19792, 19793, 19794, 19795, 19796, 19797, 19798, 
19799, 19800, 19801, 19802, 19803, 19804, 19805, 19806, 19807, 
19808, 19809, 19810, 19811, 19812, 19813, 19814, 19815, 19816, 
19817, 19818, 19819, 19820, 19821, 19822, 19823, 19824, 19825, 
19826, 19827, 19828, 19829, 19830, 19831, 19832, 19833, 19834, 
19835, 19836, 19837, 19838, 19839, 19840, 19841, 19842, 19843, 
19844, 19845, 19846, 19847, 19848, 19849, 19850, 19851, 19852, 
19853, 19854, 19855, 19856, 19857, 19858, 19859, 19860, 19861, 
19862, 19863, 19864, 19865, 19866, 19867, 19868, 19869, 19870, 
19871, 19872, 19873, 19874, 19875, 19876, 19877, 19878, 19879, 
19880, 19881, 19882, 19883, 19884, 19885, 19886, 19887, 19888, 
19889, 19890, 19891, 19892, 19893, 19894, 19895, 19896, 19897, 
19898, 19899, 19900, 19901, 19902, 19903, 19904, 19905, 19906, 
19907, 19908, 19909, 19910, 19911, 19912, 19913, 19914, 19915, 
19916, 19917, 19918, 19919, 19920, 19921, 19922, 19923, 19924, 
19925, 19926, 19927, 19928, 19929, 19930, 19931, 19932, 19933, 
19934, 19935, 19936, 19937, 19938, 19939, 19940, 19941, 19942, 
19943, 19944, 19945, 19946, 19947, 19948, 19949, 19950, 19951, 
19952, 19953, 19954, 19955, 19956, 19957, 19958, 19959, 19960, 
19961, 19962, 19963, 19964, 19965, 19966, 19967, 19968, 19969, 
19970, 19971, 19972, 19973, 19974, 19975, 19976, 19977, 19978, 
19979, 19980, 19981, 19982, 19983, 19984, 19985, 19986, 19987, 
19988, 19989, 19990, 19991, 19992, 19993, 19994, 19995, 19996, 
19997, 19998, 19999, 20000, 20001, 20002, 20003, 20004, 20005, 
20006, 20007, 20008, 20009, 20010, 20011, 20012, 20013, 20014, 
20015, 20016, 20017, 20018, 20019, 20020, 20021, 20022, 20023, 
20024, 20025, 20026, 20027, 20028, 20029, 20030, 20031, 20032, 
20033, 20034, 20035, 20036, 20037, 20038, 20039, 20040, 20041, 
20042, 20043, 20044, 20045, 20046, 20047, 20048, 20049, 20050, 
20051, 20052, 20053, 20054, 20055, 20056, 20057, 20058, 20059, 
20060, 20061, 20062, 20063, 20064, 20065, 20066, 20067, 20068, 
20069, 20070, 20071, 20072, 20073, 20074, 20075, 20076, 20077, 
20078, 20079, 20080, 20081, 20082, 20083, 20084, 20085, 20086, 
20087, 20088, 20089), class = "Date"), Fajr = structure(c(1704085200, 
1704171723.59757, 1704258247.15872, 1704344770.64703, 1704431294.02611, 
1704517817.2596, 1704604340.31118, 1704690863.14458, 1704777385.72362, 
1704863908.01215, 1704950429.97415, 1705036951.57367, 1705123472.77488, 
1705209993.54205, 1705296513.83959, 1705383033.63207, 1705469552.88416, 
1705556071.56072, 1705642589.62679, 1705729107.04757, 1705815623.78845, 
1705902139.81502, 1705988655.0931, 1706075169.58872, 1706161683.26812, 
1706248196.09781, 1706334708.04454, 1706421219.07531, 1706507729.1574, 
1706594238.25838, 1706680746.34609, 1706767253.38867, 1706853759.35458, 
1706940264.2126, 1707026767.93181, 1707113270.48165, 1707199771.83191, 
1707286271.9527, 1707372770.81454, 1707459268.38827, 1707545764.64515, 
1707632259.5568, 1707718753.09527, 1707805245.23297, 1707891735.94277, 
1707978225.19791, 1708064712.97211, 1708151199.2395, 1708237683.97464, 
1708324167.15257, 1708410648.74878, 1708497128.73921, 1708583607.1003, 
1708670083.80895, 1708756558.84256, 1708843032.17901, 1708929503.79669, 
1709015973.6745, 1709102441.79183, 1709188908.12862, 1709275372.66532, 
1709361835.38291, 1709448296.2629, 1709534755.28735, 1709621212.43887, 
1709707667.70061, 1709794121.05629, 1709880572.49019, 1709967021.98715, 
1710053469.53257, 1710139915.11245, 1710226358.71336, 1710312800.32245, 
1710399239.92745, 1710485677.51669, 1710572113.07909, 1710658546.60418, 
1710744978.08207, 1710831407.50349, 1710917834.85977, 1711004260.14284, 
1711090683.34525, 1711177104.46017, 1711263523.48137, 1711349940.40325, 
1711436355.22082, 1711522767.92972, 1711609178.52619, 1711695587.00712, 
1711781993.37, 1711864797.61297, 1711951199.73476, 1712037599.73476, 
1712123997.61297, 1712210393.37, 1712296787.00712, 1712383178.52619, 
1712469567.92972, 1712555955.22082, 1712642340.40325, 1712728723.48137, 
1712815104.46017, 1712901483.34525, 1712987860.14284, 1713074234.85977, 
1713160607.50349, 1713246978.08207, 1713333346.60418, 1713419713.07909, 
1713506077.51669, 1713592439.92745, 1713678800.32245, 1713765158.71336, 
1713851515.11245, 1713937869.53257, 1714024221.98715, 1714110572.49019, 
1714196921.05629, 1714283267.70061, 1714369612.43887, 1714455955.28735, 
1714542296.2629, 1714628635.38291, 1714714972.66532, 1714801308.12862, 
1714887641.79183, 1714973973.6745, 1715060303.79669, 1715146632.17901, 
1715232958.84256, 1715319283.80895, 1715405607.1003, 1715491928.73921, 
1715578248.74878, 1715664567.15257, 1715750883.97464, 1715837199.2395, 
1715923512.97211, 1716009825.19791, 1716096135.94277, 1716182445.23297, 
1716268753.09527, 1716355059.5568, 1716441364.64515, 1716527668.38827, 
1716613970.81454, 1716700271.9527, 1716786571.83191, 1716872870.48165, 
1716959167.93181, 1717045464.2126, 1717131759.35458, 1717218053.38867, 
1717304346.34609, 1717390638.25838, 1717476929.1574, 1717563219.07531, 
1717649508.04454, 1717735796.09781, 1717822083.26812, 1717908369.58872, 
1717994655.0931, 1718080939.81502, 1718167223.78845, 1718253507.04757, 
1718339789.62679, 1718426071.56072, 1718512352.88416, 1718598633.63207, 
1718684913.83959, 1718771193.54205, 1718857472.77488, 1718943751.57367, 
1719030029.97415, 1719116308.01215, 1719202585.72362, 1719288863.14458, 
1719375140.31118, 1719461417.2596, 1719547694.02611, 1719633970.64703, 
1719720247.15872, 1719806523.59757, 1719892800, 1719979076.40243, 
1720065352.84128, 1720151629.35297, 1720237905.97389, 1720324182.7404, 
1720410459.68882, 1720496736.85542, 1720583014.27638, 1720669291.98785, 
1720755570.02585, 1720841848.42633, 1720928127.22512, 1721014406.45795, 
1721100686.16041, 1721186966.36793, 1721273247.11584, 1721359528.43928, 
1721445810.37321, 1721532092.95243, 1721618376.21155, 1721704660.18498, 
1721790944.9069, 1721877230.41128, 1721963516.73188, 1722049803.90219, 
1722136091.95546, 1722222380.92469, 1722308670.8426, 1722394961.74162, 
1722481253.65391, 1722567546.61133, 1722653840.64542, 1722740135.7874, 
1722826432.06819, 1722912729.51835, 1722999028.16809, 1723085328.0473, 
1723171629.18546, 1723257931.61173, 1723344235.35485, 1723430540.4432, 
1723516846.90473, 1723603154.76703, 1723689464.05723, 1723775774.80209, 
1723862087.02789, 1723948400.7605, 1724034716.02536, 1724121032.84743, 
1724207351.25122, 1724293671.26079, 1724379992.8997, 1724466316.19105, 
1724552641.15744, 1724638967.82099, 1724725296.20331, 1724811626.3255, 
1724897958.20817, 1724984291.87138, 1725070627.33468, 1725156964.61709, 
1725243303.7371, 1725329644.71265, 1725415987.56113, 1725502332.29939, 
1725588678.94371, 1725675027.50981, 1725761378.01285, 1725847730.46743, 
1725934084.88755, 1726020441.28664, 1726106799.67755, 1726193160.07255, 
1726279522.48331, 1726365886.92091, 1726452253.39582, 1726538621.91793, 
1726624992.49651, 1726711365.14023, 1726797739.85716, 1726884116.65475, 
1726970495.53983, 1727056876.51863, 1727143259.59675, 1727229644.77918, 
1727316032.07028, 1727402421.47381, 1727488812.99288, 1727575206.63, 
1727661602.38703, 1727748000.26524, 1727834400.26524, 1727920802.38703, 
1728007206.63, 1728093612.99288, 1728180021.47381, 1728266432.07028, 
1728352844.77918, 1728439259.59675, 1728525676.51863, 1728612095.53983, 
1728698516.65475, 1728784939.85716, 1728871365.14023, 1728957792.49651, 
1729044221.91793, 1729130653.39582, 1729217086.92091, 1729303522.48331, 
1729389960.07255, 1729476399.67755, 1729562841.28664, 1729649284.88755, 
1729735730.46743, 1729822178.01285, 1729908627.50981, 1729998678.94371, 
1730085132.29939, 1730171587.56113, 1730258044.71265, 1730344503.7371, 
1730430964.61709, 1730517427.33468, 1730603891.87138, 1730690358.20817, 
1730776826.3255, 1730863296.20331, 1730949767.82099, 1731036241.15744, 
1731122716.19105, 1731209192.8997, 1731295671.26079, 1731382151.25122, 
1731468632.84743, 1731555116.02536, 1731641600.7605, 1731728087.02789, 
1731814574.80209, 1731901064.05723, 1731987554.76703, 1732074046.90473, 
1732160540.4432, 1732247035.35485, 1732333531.61173, 1732420029.18546, 
1732506528.0473, 1732593028.16809, 1732679529.51835, 1732766032.06819, 
1732852535.7874, 1732939040.64542, 1733025546.61133, 1733112053.65391, 
1733198561.74162, 1733285070.8426, 1733371580.92469, 1733458091.95546, 
1733544603.90219, 1733631116.73188, 1733717630.41128, 1733804144.9069, 
1733890660.18498, 1733977176.21155, 1734063692.95243, 1734150210.37321, 
1734236728.43928, 1734323247.11584, 1734409766.36793, 1734496286.16041, 
1734582806.45795, 1734669327.22512, 1734755848.42633, 1734842370.02585, 
1734928891.98785, 1735015414.27638, 1735101936.85542, 1735188459.68882, 
1735274982.7404, 1735361505.97389, 1735448029.35297, 1735534552.84128, 
1735621076.40243, 1735707600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    Dhuhr = structure(c(1704106800, 1704193292.69818, 1704279785.36904, 
    1704366277.98528, 1704452770.51959, 1704539262.9447, 1704625755.23338, 
    1704712247.35844, 1704798739.29271, 1704885231.00911, 1704971722.48061, 
    1705058213.68025, 1705144704.58116, 1705231195.15654, 1705317685.3797, 
    1705404175.22405, 1705490664.66312, 1705577153.67054, 1705663642.22009, 
    1705750130.28568, 1705836617.84133, 1705923104.86127, 1706009591.31983, 
    1706096077.19154, 1706182562.45109, 1706269047.07336, 1706355531.0334, 
    1706442014.30648, 1706528496.86805, 1706614978.69379, 1706701459.75957, 
    1706787940.0415, 1706874419.51594, 1706960898.15945, 1707047375.94886, 
    1707133852.86124, 1707220328.87393, 1707306803.96453, 1707393278.1109, 
    1707479751.2912, 1707566223.48386, 1707652694.6676, 1707739164.82145, 
    1707825633.92473, 1707912101.95707, 1707998568.89844, 1708085034.72908, 
    1708171499.42962, 1708257962.98098, 1708344425.36443, 1708430886.56158, 
    1708517346.55441, 1708603805.32523, 1708690262.85672, 1708776719.13192, 
    1708863174.13426, 1708949627.84752, 1709036080.25587, 1709122531.34387, 
    1709208981.09647, 1709295429.49899, 1709381876.53718, 1709468322.19717, 
    1709554766.46551, 1709641209.32915, 1709727650.77546, 1709814090.79222, 
    1709900529.36764, 1709986966.49036, 1710073402.14943, 1710159836.33434, 
    1710246269.03502, 1710332700.24184, 1710419129.94558, 1710505558.13751, 
    1710591984.80932, 1710678409.95313, 1710764833.56155, 1710851255.62762, 
    1710937676.14482, 1711024095.10713, 1711110512.50894, 1711196928.34513, 
    1711283342.61103, 1711369755.30244, 1711456166.41562, 1711542575.94729, 
    1711628983.89464, 1711715390.25534, 1711801795.0275, 1711884598.20972, 
    1711970999.80107, 1712057399.80107, 1712143798.20972, 1712230195.0275, 
    1712316590.25534, 1712402983.89464, 1712489375.94729, 1712575766.41562, 
    1712662155.30244, 1712748542.61103, 1712834928.34513, 1712921312.50894, 
    1713007695.10713, 1713094076.14482, 1713180455.62762, 1713266833.56155, 
    1713353209.95313, 1713439584.80932, 1713525958.13751, 1713612329.94558, 
    1713698700.24184, 1713785069.03502, 1713871436.33434, 1713957802.14943, 
    1714044166.49036, 1714130529.36764, 1714216890.79222, 1714303250.77546, 
    1714389609.32915, 1714475966.46551, 1714562322.19717, 1714648676.53718, 
    1714735029.49899, 1714821381.09647, 1714907731.34387, 1714994080.25587, 
    1715080427.84752, 1715166774.13426, 1715253119.13192, 1715339462.85672, 
    1715425805.32523, 1715512146.55441, 1715598486.56158, 1715684825.36443, 
    1715771162.98098, 1715857499.42962, 1715943834.72908, 1716030168.89844, 
    1716116501.95707, 1716202833.92473, 1716289164.82145, 1716375494.6676, 
    1716461823.48386, 1716548151.2912, 1716634478.1109, 1716720803.96453, 
    1716807128.87393, 1716893452.86124, 1716979775.94886, 1717066098.15945, 
    1717152419.51594, 1717238740.0415, 1717325059.75957, 1717411378.69379, 
    1717497696.86805, 1717584014.30648, 1717670331.0334, 1717756647.07336, 
    1717842962.45109, 1717929277.19154, 1718015591.31983, 1718101904.86127, 
    1718188217.84133, 1718274530.28568, 1718360842.22009, 1718447153.67054, 
    1718533464.66312, 1718619775.22405, 1718706085.3797, 1718792395.15654, 
    1718878704.58116, 1718965013.68025, 1719051322.48061, 1719137631.00911, 
    1719223939.29271, 1719310247.35844, 1719396555.23338, 1719482862.9447, 
    1719569170.51959, 1719655477.98528, 1719741785.36904, 1719828092.69818, 
    1719914400, 1720000707.30182, 1720087014.63096, 1720173322.01472, 
    1720259629.48041, 1720345937.0553, 1720432244.76662, 1720518552.64156, 
    1720604860.70729, 1720691168.99089, 1720777477.51939, 1720863786.31975, 
    1720950095.41884, 1721036404.84346, 1721122714.6203, 1721209024.77595, 
    1721295335.33688, 1721381646.32946, 1721467957.77991, 1721554269.71432, 
    1721640582.15867, 1721726895.13873, 1721813208.68017, 1721899522.80846, 
    1721985837.54891, 1722072152.92664, 1722158468.9666, 1722244785.69352, 
    1722331103.13195, 1722417421.30621, 1722503740.24043, 1722590059.9585, 
    1722676380.48406, 1722762701.84055, 1722849024.05114, 1722935347.13876, 
    1723021671.12607, 1723107996.03547, 1723194321.8891, 1723280648.7088, 
    1723366976.51614, 1723453305.3324, 1723539635.17855, 1723625966.07527, 
    1723712298.04293, 1723798631.10156, 1723884965.27092, 1723971300.57038, 
    1724057637.01902, 1724143974.63557, 1724230313.43842, 1724316653.44559, 
    1724402994.67477, 1724489337.14328, 1724575680.86808, 1724662025.86574, 
    1724748372.15248, 1724834719.74413, 1724921068.65613, 1725007418.90353, 
    1725093770.50101, 1725180123.46282, 1725266477.80283, 1725352833.53449, 
    1725439190.67085, 1725525549.22454, 1725611909.20778, 1725698270.63236, 
    1725784633.50964, 1725870997.85057, 1725957363.66566, 1726043730.96498, 
    1726130099.75816, 1726216470.05442, 1726302841.86249, 1726389215.19068, 
    1726475590.04687, 1726561966.43845, 1726648344.37238, 1726734723.85518, 
    1726821104.89287, 1726907487.49106, 1726993871.65487, 1727080257.38897, 
    1727166644.69756, 1727253033.58438, 1727339424.05271, 1727425816.10536, 
    1727512209.74466, 1727598604.9725, 1727685001.79028, 1727771400.19893, 
    1727857800.19893, 1727944201.79028, 1728030604.9725, 1728117009.74466, 
    1728203416.10536, 1728289824.05271, 1728376233.58438, 1728462644.69756, 
    1728549057.38897, 1728635471.65487, 1728721887.49106, 1728808304.89287, 
    1728894723.85518, 1728981144.37238, 1729067566.43845, 1729153990.04687, 
    1729240415.19068, 1729326841.86249, 1729413270.05442, 1729499699.75816, 
    1729586130.96498, 1729672563.66566, 1729758997.85057, 1729845433.50964, 
    1729931870.63236, 1730021909.20778, 1730108349.22454, 1730194790.67085, 
    1730281233.53449, 1730367677.80283, 1730454123.46282, 1730540570.50101, 
    1730627018.90353, 1730713468.65613, 1730799919.74413, 1730886372.15248, 
    1730972825.86574, 1731059280.86808, 1731145737.14328, 1731232194.67477, 
    1731318653.44559, 1731405113.43842, 1731491574.63557, 1731578037.01902, 
    1731664500.57038, 1731750965.27092, 1731837431.10156, 1731923898.04293, 
    1732010366.07527, 1732096835.17855, 1732183305.3324, 1732269776.51614, 
    1732356248.7088, 1732442721.8891, 1732529196.03547, 1732615671.12607, 
    1732702147.13876, 1732788624.05114, 1732875101.84055, 1732961580.48406, 
    1733048059.9585, 1733134540.24043, 1733221021.30621, 1733307503.13195, 
    1733393985.69352, 1733480468.9666, 1733566952.92664, 1733653437.54891, 
    1733739922.80846, 1733826408.68017, 1733912895.13873, 1733999382.15867, 
    1734085869.71432, 1734172357.77991, 1734258846.32946, 1734345335.33688, 
    1734431824.77595, 1734518314.6203, 1734604804.84346, 1734691295.41884, 
    1734777786.31975, 1734864277.51939, 1734950768.99089, 1735037260.70729, 
    1735123752.64156, 1735210244.76662, 1735296737.0553, 1735383229.48041, 
    1735469722.01472, 1735556214.63096, 1735642707.30182, 1735729200
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Maghrib = structure(c(1704128400, 
    1704214861.79879, 1704301323.57936, 1704387785.32352, 1704474247.01306, 
    1704560708.6298, 1704647170.15559, 1704733631.57229, 1704820092.86181, 
    1704906554.00608, 1704993014.98708, 1705079475.78684, 1705165936.38744, 
    1705252396.77102, 1705338856.9198, 1705425316.81603, 1705511776.44208, 
    1705598235.78036, 1705684694.8134, 1705771153.52378, 1705857611.89422, 
    1705944069.90751, 1706030527.54655, 1706116984.79436, 1706203441.63406, 
    1706289898.04891, 1706376354.02227, 1706462809.53765, 1706549264.5787, 
    1706635719.12919, 1706722173.17304, 1706808626.69434, 1706895079.67729, 
    1706981532.1063, 1707067983.9659, 1707154435.24083, 1707240885.91595, 
    1707327335.97635, 1707413785.40727, 1707500234.19413, 1707586682.32257, 
    1707673129.7784, 1707759576.54763, 1707846022.61649, 1707932467.97138, 
    1708018912.59896, 1708105356.48606, 1708191799.61975, 1708278241.98732, 
    1708364683.57628, 1708451124.37439, 1708537564.36961, 1708624003.55015, 
    1708710441.90448, 1708796879.42128, 1708883316.08951, 1708969751.89835, 
    1709056186.83725, 1709142620.89592, 1709229054.06431, 1709315486.33266, 
    1709401917.69145, 1709488348.13145, 1709574777.64367, 1709661206.21943, 
    1709747633.85031, 1709834060.52815, 1709920486.2451, 1710006910.99357, 
    1710093334.76629, 1710179757.55623, 1710266179.35668, 1710352600.16122, 
    1710439019.96372, 1710525438.75834, 1710611856.53955, 1710698273.30209, 
    1710784689.04104, 1710871103.75175, 1710957517.42988, 1711043930.07142, 
    1711130341.67263, 1711216752.23009, 1711303161.74069, 1711389570.20163, 
    1711475977.61041, 1711562383.96486, 1711648789.2631, 1711735193.50356, 
    1711821596.685, 1711904398.80648, 1711990799.86738, 1712077199.86738, 
    1712163598.80648, 1712249996.685, 1712336393.50356, 1712422789.2631, 
    1712509183.96486, 1712595577.61041, 1712681970.20163, 1712768361.74069, 
    1712854752.23009, 1712941141.67263, 1713027530.07142, 1713113917.42988, 
    1713200303.75175, 1713286689.04104, 1713373073.30209, 1713459456.53955, 
    1713545838.75834, 1713632219.96372, 1713718600.16122, 1713804979.35668, 
    1713891357.55623, 1713977734.76629, 1714064110.99357, 1714150486.2451, 
    1714236860.52815, 1714323233.85031, 1714409606.21943, 1714495977.64367, 
    1714582348.13145, 1714668717.69145, 1714755086.33266, 1714841454.06431, 
    1714927820.89592, 1715014186.83725, 1715100551.89835, 1715186916.08951, 
    1715273279.42128, 1715359641.90448, 1715446003.55015, 1715532364.36961, 
    1715618724.37439, 1715705083.57628, 1715791441.98732, 1715877799.61975, 
    1715964156.48606, 1716050512.59896, 1716136867.97138, 1716223222.61649, 
    1716309576.54763, 1716395929.7784, 1716482282.32257, 1716568634.19413, 
    1716654985.40727, 1716741335.97635, 1716827685.91595, 1716914035.24083, 
    1717000383.9659, 1717086732.1063, 1717173079.67729, 1717259426.69434, 
    1717345773.17304, 1717432119.12919, 1717518464.5787, 1717604809.53765, 
    1717691154.02227, 1717777498.04891, 1717863841.63406, 1717950184.79436, 
    1718036527.54655, 1718122869.90751, 1718209211.89422, 1718295553.52378, 
    1718381894.8134, 1718468235.78036, 1718554576.44208, 1718640916.81603, 
    1718727256.9198, 1718813596.77102, 1718899936.38744, 1718986275.78684, 
    1719072614.98708, 1719158954.00608, 1719245292.86181, 1719331631.57229, 
    1719417970.15559, 1719504308.6298, 1719590647.01306, 1719676985.32352, 
    1719763323.57936, 1719849661.79879, 1719936000, 1720022338.20121, 
    1720108676.42064, 1720195014.67648, 1720281352.98694, 1720367691.3702, 
    1720454029.84441, 1720540368.42771, 1720626707.13819, 1720713045.99392, 
    1720799385.01292, 1720885724.21316, 1720972063.61256, 1721058403.22898, 
    1721144743.0802, 1721231083.18397, 1721317423.55792, 1721403764.21964, 
    1721490105.1866, 1721576446.47622, 1721662788.10578, 1721749130.09249, 
    1721835472.45345, 1721921815.20564, 1722008158.36594, 1722094501.95109, 
    1722180845.97773, 1722267190.46235, 1722353535.4213, 1722439880.87081, 
    1722526226.82696, 1722612573.30566, 1722698920.32271, 1722785267.8937, 
    1722871616.0341, 1722957964.75917, 1723044314.08405, 1723130664.02365, 
    1723217014.59273, 1723303365.80587, 1723389717.67743, 1723476070.2216, 
    1723562423.45237, 1723648777.38351, 1723735132.02862, 1723821487.40104, 
    1723907843.51394, 1723994200.38025, 1724080558.01268, 1724166916.42372, 
    1724253275.62561, 1724339635.63039, 1724425996.44985, 1724512358.09552, 
    1724598720.57872, 1724685083.91049, 1724771448.10165, 1724857813.16275, 
    1724944179.10408, 1725030545.93569, 1725116913.66734, 1725203282.30855, 
    1725289651.86855, 1725376022.35633, 1725462393.78057, 1725548766.14969, 
    1725635139.47185, 1725721513.7549, 1725807889.00643, 1725894265.23371, 
    1725980642.44377, 1726067020.64332, 1726153399.83878, 1726239780.03628, 
    1726326161.24166, 1726412543.46045, 1726498926.69791, 1726585310.95896, 
    1726671696.24825, 1726758082.57012, 1726844469.92858, 1726930858.32737, 
    1727017247.76991, 1727103638.25931, 1727190029.79837, 1727276422.38959, 
    1727362816.03514, 1727449210.7369, 1727535606.49644, 1727622003.315, 
    1727708401.19352, 1727794800.13262, 1727881200.13262, 1727967601.19352, 
    1728054003.315, 1728140406.49644, 1728226810.7369, 1728313216.03514, 
    1728399622.38959, 1728486029.79837, 1728572438.25931, 1728658847.76991, 
    1728745258.32737, 1728831669.92858, 1728918082.57012, 1729004496.24825, 
    1729090910.95896, 1729177326.69791, 1729263743.46045, 1729350161.24166, 
    1729436580.03628, 1729522999.83878, 1729609420.64332, 1729695842.44377, 
    1729782265.23371, 1729868689.00643, 1729955113.7549, 1730045139.47185, 
    1730131566.14969, 1730217993.78057, 1730304422.35633, 1730390851.86855, 
    1730477282.30855, 1730563713.66734, 1730650145.93569, 1730736579.10408, 
    1730823013.16275, 1730909448.10165, 1730995883.91049, 1731082320.57872, 
    1731168758.09552, 1731255196.44985, 1731341635.63039, 1731428075.62561, 
    1731514516.42372, 1731600958.01268, 1731687400.38025, 1731773843.51394, 
    1731860287.40104, 1731946732.02862, 1732033177.38351, 1732119623.45237, 
    1732206070.2216, 1732292517.67743, 1732378965.80587, 1732465414.59273, 
    1732551864.02365, 1732638314.08405, 1732724764.75917, 1732811216.0341, 
    1732897667.8937, 1732984120.32271, 1733070573.30566, 1733157026.82696, 
    1733243480.87081, 1733329935.4213, 1733416390.46235, 1733502845.97773, 
    1733589301.95109, 1733675758.36594, 1733762215.20564, 1733848672.45345, 
    1733935130.09249, 1734021588.10578, 1734108046.47622, 1734194505.1866, 
    1734280964.21964, 1734367423.55792, 1734453883.18397, 1734540343.0802, 
    1734626803.22898, 1734713263.61256, 1734799724.21316, 1734886185.01292, 
    1734972645.99392, 1735059107.13819, 1735145568.42771, 1735232029.84441, 
    1735318491.3702, 1735404952.98694, 1735491414.67648, 1735577876.42064, 
    1735664338.20121, 1735750800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ))), row.names = c(NA, -367L), class = "data.frame")


Thank you for your reply. Much appreciated it. I've tried as you suggested however I got this error:
Error in -.POSIXt(x, as.POSIXct(data$Date)) :
can only subtract from "POSIXt" objects.
Do you have any suggestions?

@aswanism  instead of df[-1], i.e. plot everything except first column, you want to plot just the prayers column. Solution: Use a vector pr, see update. In addition you probably have to correct the dates, try df[pr] <- lapply(df[pr], \(x) x + difftime(df$Date, as.POSIXct(as.Date(x)), units='secs')).
